# CoreML for Game AI with multiple inputs and multiple outputs

Tags: swift, neural-network, game-development, coreml

I'm playing around making a 2D game, and I'd like an AI enemy to chase/attack/avoid the main character under certain circumstances.

I've been thinking what would the AI need to do:

1. Process what it can see
2. Move up, down, left, right
3. Attack

Given the prominence of CoreML, could I build a *.mlmodel that could take in for example, a picture of the scene, and some other inputs, and output five messages, like, up, down, left, right, attack

The way I see it working would be, for every frame of the game:

1. get the inputs
2. Send to CoreML for processing
3. CoreML returns all 5 outputs
4. Enemy AI, actions those outputs.

Is this something CoreML could handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible to train a machine learning model to perform these actions given the right circumstances, I believe that [GameplayKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gameplaykit) is closer to what you're looking for.

Specifically, the chase / attack / avoid actions that you describe are similar to actions in the ["DemoBots" sample code project](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/DemoBots/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015179) from a few years ago. That should be a good place to start. The [Deeper into GameplayKit with DemoBots WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/609/) might also be a good resource.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Core ML can do this. However, the real issue here isn't Core ML, it's creating (training) the model.

Also, for your game it's probably easier -- and a lot faster -- to just use a handful of rules for the enemy AI than using a machine learning model.